# Passing an item in a class for use in another form

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've put together the LINQ to XML model following [ScottGu's Tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/07/using-linq-to-xml-and-how-to-build-a-custom-rss-feed-reader-with-it.aspx), which returns an RSS feed, which I can then use a foreach loop to get data out of when i put it the same .cs file.

I've then put this into its own class, as to call from code, but I can't access the "items" from my other page to perform a ForEach loop. I'm pretty new to this, and was wondering what I need to write?

Heres my rss reader (built loosely from scotts) in its own .cs file. I can access DataAnswerFeed but not "var items". Do I need a way to return a value?

```
public class DataAnswerFeed
    {
        public string AnsID { get; set; }
        public string AnsQueID { get; set; }
        public string AnsText { get; set; }
        public string Correct { get; set; }
    }
public class AnswerFeed
{

   public AnswerFeed()
    {
        WebClient feed = new WebClient();
        feed.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(feed_DownloadStringCompleted);
        feed.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://myRssFeed.xml"));
    }

    private static readonly XNamespace m = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";

    public void feed_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        XElement uri = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
        var items = (from item in uri.Descendants(m + "properties")
                     select new DataAnswerFeed()
                     {
                         AnsID = item.Descendants().ToList()[0].Value,
                         AnsQueID = item.Descendants().ToList()[1].Value,
                         AnsText = item.Descendants().ToList()[2].Value,
                         Correct = item.Descendants().ToList()[3].Value
                     }).ToList();

    }
}
```

}

In my other page i write DataAnswerFeed newFeed = new DataAnswerFeed();
I'm then trying to run the ForEach loop the same way that I would within the class, but get an error saying theres no public definition for "GetEnumerator"?

after declaring newFeed, heres my foreach in a seperate void.

```
 public void testPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ForEach loop on the list
        foreach (DataAnswerFeed a in newFeed)
        {
            //Show test data to check working
            MessageBox.Show(a.AnsText);
        }

    }
```

Thanks...

Comment: what type is thiss? is it a typo, did you mean `this` instead?

Comment: sorry no, it was just general notation as I declared newFeed... thiss should read newFeed

Comment: I'm afraid your current approach won't work at all since you retrieve the feed asynchronously, even if you expose a public List as suggested below. The Silverlight way to do it would be to update a model property which is then used by some UI element - you shouldn't loop directly over the received data in the first place.

Comment: Ah guess it looks like that's something i'll have to look into. Didn't realize the asynchronous call caused the difference! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `AnswerFeed` class

```
   public static List<DataAnswerFeed> Answers = new List<DataAnswerFeed>();
```

then assign the result of your query to it

```
   Answers = (from item in uri.Descendants(m + "properties") ...
```

In `testPage_Loaded`:

```
   foreach (DataAnswerFeed a in AnswerFeed.Answers)
```

It's not nice to have statics, but it will work ;)

Comment: Thanks. This passed the value over, so I can see it, but it gives me it as a list with count 0 items, so there's no data to pass.

Is using ToList(); at the end of my select query enough to pass it to Answers?

Comment: yes it should be, are you sure feed_DownloadStringCompleted is executed, before you show the answers?

Comment: My code is as above, with the modifications you suggested. It worked when I had the forEach below, so maybe it's because of my other page?

i'm using "foreach (DataAnswerFeed a in AnswerFeed.Answers)
            {
                //Show test data to check working
                MessageBox.Show(a.AnsText);
            }"

what classes should i be declaring to what? That could be it